# How do I format 7 as '07' in string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript day, month and year. I need my day to be in 2 digits, my months also to be in 2 digits and year in 4 digits.

**Eg.** If month is `7` it should give me string as `'07'`. If it is `12` then it should return `'12'`.

I google for it but I only found `toFixed` and `toPrecision`, both of which have different functions. How do I format it?

Comment: Isn't that like a one-line function to write? Although there's an [sprintf for JavaScript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Comment: I get sprintf  is not defined. Is this supported on all browsers?

Comment: @TimTom it's not in browsers but custom code that you have to include, hence the link to the project

Comment: There's no built-in `sprintf` function, that page is about a custom implementation which you need to download and include yourself. In my opinion, it's overkill if you only need this to pad a number with zeroes.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens +1 for overkill... but it didn't seem like the OP was really attempting to apply themselves, so I figured what the heck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var newmonth = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month; // if month is number
                                                 // else use parseInt(month, 10)
```

You can also make a function for general use:

```
function formatting(target) {
  return target < 10 ? '0' + target : target;
}
```

You can use above approach for month and days.

and to get a 4 digits year you can use [`.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

Comment: And if you're using `parseInt()` use the radix: `parseInt(month,10)`.

Comment: Also, the ternary operator syntax is `a ? b : c`, you typed `a : b : c`. I tried to issue an edit, but it says my edit is too short. :P

Comment: i think you mean `... ? ... : ...`

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like this...

```
mth = ("0" + mth).slice(-2);
```

---

Also, keep in mind that months are `0` based, so you may want this...

```
mth = ("0" + ++mth).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at a sprintf library for Javascript, if you're looking for more robust functionality than a simple zero-padding function.

http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Underscore.string has an implementation as well.

https://github.com/edtsech/underscore.string

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = 7;
let paddedNumber = number.toString().padStart(2, '0');
console.log(paddedNumber);
```

output:-
07

If the original string is already longer than the specified length, no padding is added

```
let number = 70;
let paddedNumber = number.toString().padStart(2, '0');
console.log(paddedNumber);
```

output:-
70