# Javascript addition query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Don't feel foolishness in my question. Below is my scenario. Please advice

var num = 02;
var add = num + 1 ;

Getting result is 3, but I need it as 03. Is it possible.

Comment: Do you mean you need a _string_ with the characters "01" in it? Or the "octal representation"? How do you intend to use this value of `03`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1267283/2034234

Comment: I don't need it as a string. I need to increment and decrement the value according to my purpose.

Comment: you need add as 03 in where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format 7 as '07' in string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864288/how-do-i-format-7-as-07-in-string-in-javascript)

Comment: If you don't need it as a string, what do you need it as? If you're doing addition, the trailing 0 is superfluous...

Comment: guys my scenario is totally different. I need an output like my query. For you better understanding I have given simple example.

Comment: "For your better understanding".... Clearly as given nobody understands what you are asking, how is `03` different from `3` _except_ when represented as a string?.... Are you outputting this result? Printing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write a padding function:

```
function strpad(string, length, padChar) 
{
    var o = string.toString();
    if(!padChar) 
    { 
       padChar = '0'; 
    }

    while (o.length < length) 
    {
        o = padChar + o;
    }
    return o;
};
```

And then call it using:

```
var num = 3;
var add = strpad((3 + 1), 2); // will return '04' as a string.
```

Comment: It will be great if you explain the code for the javascript starters :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
<script>
var num=2;
var add= parseInt(num + 2);

if(parseInt(add) <10)
   {
      add= '0'+add; // if single digit no. then concat 0 before the no.
   }

</script>
```